# Protractor Max Call Stack Error

Tags: selenium, jasmine, protractor

I've been using Protractor for quite awhile now and am familiar with a range of errors related to Protractor, Webdriver, Jasmine etc.  Recently, I've encountered one I haven't seen before:

```
A Jasmine spec timed out. Resetting the WebDriver Control Flow.

/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:714
    super(opt_msg);
         ^
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

While I have seen maximum call stack errors before, they are typically related to recursive functions or ridiculously large `for` loops.

So I am a little lost on what this means for Protractor/Webdriver.  Per my understanding, this is a browser-related error. But I don't have much JavaScript going directly to the browser (just some forced clicks, and logging a few objects).

Also, I have only seen this error while running my entire suite of tests (~500 specs), but it does **not** happen every time and it also does not occur in the same spot which concerns me... it's a flaky error.

Does anyone have an explanation for this error?

Comment: even am facing the same error when tried using large promise inside expect statement.i have googled a lot and ended up with no solution.So in many situations, I need to resolve the promise explicitly and use the result in expect statement.

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons `Maximum call stack size exceeded` error occurs is when a function calls itself. For example

```
let next = async function () {
    await $nextButton.click();
    await next(); // function calls itself here
}
```

What happens here is the code gets in an infinite loop and throws the error

Thus just go over your code and make sure you don't do it somewhere by accident